# Angular : how to keep a header fixed and always appearent when scrolling a dropdwon options list

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Under my App , i ve a **mat-select** widget, it's a list of options which i'm used to scroll within the list to see all the options:

I want to add a header on the top of the the options list , thus , it keeps always appearent while scrolling

```
<mat-select placeholder="Selectionner la boutique"
                        id="libelleShop"
                        #inputSelectShop
                        [(value)]="selectedlibelleShopoValue"
                        ngDefaultControl
                        formControlName="libelleShop"
                        (selectionChange)="onShopSelectionChanged($event)">
              /* THIS IS MY HEADER DIV */
              <div id="myHeader" class="m-2">
                <span class="myHeaderClass"></span>
              </div>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of bad3ShopsListSortedByName"
                          [value]="shop.edoId">
                {{shop.storeName}}
              </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

How may i fix this div to be always on the top , and prevent it to diseppear while scrolling to the bottom of the list

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: have you tried CSS `position : sticky;` ?

Comment: @Adil it s no making any change

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your css (you are missing the top: xxx px value)  as this determines where to stick to exactly.

```
.m-2 {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0px;
   z-index:1000;
   margin-bottom: <whatever you need>px;

}
```

Comment: that s better yeah , but something is missing , initially it's good , but when scrolling the options seems to be displayed in the same plan space with the searrch input , i think there is some margin to put

Comment: you can use z-index if needed, and I guess margin too.  I dont know exactly what you want or how big everthing is or should be